# refresh div ajax when inserting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem, I want the div refreshes when the ajax function end

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function($) {
    // Quando o formulário for enviado, essa função é chamada
    $("#da-ex-validate1").submit(function() {
        // Colocamos os valores de cada campo em uma váriavel para facilitar a manipulação
        var mensagem = $("#cleditor").val();
        var user = $("#user").val();
        // Exibe mensagem de carregamento
        $("#status").html("<img src='loader.gif' alt='Enviando' />");
        // Fazemos a requisão ajax com o arquivo envia.php e enviamos os valores de cada campo através do método POST
        $.post('<?= URL::getBase();?>form/insert/comment.php?id=<?=$_id;?>', {user: user, mensagem: mensagem }, function(resposta) {
                // Quando terminada a requisição
                // Exibe a div status
                $("#status").slideDown();
                // Se a resposta é um erro
                if (resposta != false) {
                    // Exibe o erro na div
                    $("#status").html(resposta);
                } 
                // Se resposta for false, ou seja, não ocorreu nenhum erro
                else {
                    // Exibe mensagem de sucesso
                    $("#status").html("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");
                    // Coloca a mensagem no div de mensagens
                    // clean fields
                    $("#cleditor").val("");
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

my html

```
  <form id="da-ex-validate1" class="da-form" method="post" action="javascript:func()" >
                                <div id="da-ex-val1-error" class="da-message error" style="display:none;"></div>     
                            <div id="mensagens">
                                <?= comments::_build($_id);?>
                             </div>   

                                <div id="responder" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="da-form-row"></div>                         
                                            <div class="da-form-inline">
                                                <div class="da-form-row">
                                                        <span class="formNote">Responder Mensagem</span>
                                                       <textarea id="cleditor" name="mensagem" class="large required"></textarea>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<? GetInfo::_id(NULL);?>"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                           

                                     </div>
                                </div>

                                        <div class="da-button-row" id="button" style="display:none;">
                                            <input type="reset" value="<?= $_LANG[137];?>" class="da-button gray left" />
                                            <input type="submit" value="<?= $_LANG[219];?>" class="da-button red" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

code is normally inserting the message, the only problem is that it does not update messages.

all messages are called in a static class type, as you can see.

Comment: Why are you passing $ as an argument to your DOM onReady function? It seems like that would cause problems.

Comment: to be honest with you, I do I schedule in js, I got this code on the internet.